# Would it be possible to turn the field test into an app?

Tags: applications, xcode, cellular-data

When you dial *3001#12345#* on an iPhone, it brings you to field test, which gives you cellular info and stuff like that. If I got the source code for this, would it be possible for me to turn it into an app using Xcode that I could just open from my home screen. It would be much easier than dialing that every time.

[image: iOS field test]

FieldTest.app:

[image: FieldTest.app]

Answer (score 2):

Field Test is already an app: /Applications/FieldTest.app!

The app icon is just hidden on the home screen, and the Phone app launches this app.

If your iPhone is jailbroken, you can edit the application Info.plist to show the icon on the home screen. In /Applications/FieldTest.app/Info.plist, edit SBAppTabs array to remove ‘hidden’, then run `uicache` as mobile.

Comment: Thank you! My phone is jail broken, so I think I’ll try that. If I wanted to, could I also sign it through Xcode?

Comment: I can’t seem to find an info.plist file in the fieldTest.app, is there something wrong? I’ve included a photo in my original question above

Comment: @user The 7th row in the picture of Filza is named "Info.plist"? :) (Don't forget to make a backup of the file)

Comment: Oh gosh I feel stupid now , guess I need to be a little more observant next time. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do I have to use something like MTerminal to run Uicache?

Comment: @user Yes or you can ssh in, but if you ssh make sure you ssh as mobile@ instead of root@. Or you can install something from the App Store; all that ‘uicache’ does is clear the home screen cached list of apps so the icon appears, like you've installed a new app.

Comment: Ok, so I’d just use mobile with alpine as the password, correct?

Comment: @user Correct, although in the future you should change that password otherwise it gives everyone on your network access to your device!

Comment: Even LTE? Or just WiFi?